Trigger DAG with config
Hi everyone, I am using Airflow v 2.9.0 on my Windows 11 PC using Docker Desktop, but when I click on Trigger button, I can't find Trigger DAG with config option
I want to pass input parameters as Config Parameters other than Variabes using Airflow UI. What can I do to enable Trigger DAG with config option. Or is there any other way to pass inputs as config parameters?

For Airflow 2.7+, if your DAG uses/has config params, only then the params input screen will appear when you click the Run button.
If you still want the Run with params options, you can explicitly set the environment variable AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__SHOW_TRIGGER_FORM_IF_NO_PARAMS=True so that the Trigger DAG w/ config button appears in the Airflow UI.
Or set the above-mentioned variable in the airflow.cfg file.
Have a look here: https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/airflow-params

To answer your second question: "Or is there any other way to pass inputs as config parameters?"
Yes the restful API doesn't have that constraint. You can pass config as the payload of the trigger api as follows:
curl \
  --request POST "https://api-host/aws_mwaa/cli" \
  --data-raw 'dags trigger my-dag --conf "{\"files\":[\"a.txt\"]}" ' \
  --header "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJK....."

But if you are looking to enable the UI to be able to input the config, then follow the answer above.
